# Скрыть панель навигации и состояния

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Как скрыть панель навигации и состояния, что бы как в играх оно выходило когда ты проводишь пальцем с нижней части экрана на вверх а не при касании по любой части.[image: Вот две панели]

Comment: попробуйте изменить тему в манифесте android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]